# What does an exclamation point raised to a power, with no preceding number, mean?

Tags: notation, factorial

In the [OEIS sequence A049210](http://oeis.org/A049210), I noticed an odd notation I haven't seen before:

`a(n) = (8*n-1)(!^8), n >= 1, a(0) = 1.`

What does the `(!^8)` mean? My first thought was something to do with factorials, but, to my knowledge, the factorial symbol must always be preceded by a number, like `3!` or `(5+n)!`. I have no idea what a `!` would mean just floating around on its own.

I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean "take the factorial of `(8*n-1)` and raise that value to the 8th power," since that would result in the numbers growing far faster than the sequence should.

In logic and computer science, `!` is often used to mean "not," such that `!false` is `true`, but I don't think that would have any application here.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context, it seems that we have a recursion $n(!^k)=(n-k)(!^k)\cdot n$ and $m(!^k)=m$ for $1\le m<k$. This makes $n(!^1)=n!$ and $n(!^2)=n!!$.

Answer (score 1):

We can read *octo factorial numbers* in the synopsis of the OEIS sequence  *[A049210](http://oeis.org/A049210)* which is addressed by OP.

> *Octo factorial numbers* are identified as [A051189](https://oeis.org/A051189) and defined as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(n!\cdot 8^n\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1, 8, 128, 3072, 98304,\ldots)
> \end{align*}
>
> Here we have a variant in some weird notation which can be written as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(-\prod_{j=0}^n\left(8j-1\right)\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1, 7, 105, 2415, 74865,\ldots)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Speculation:

What I see when I visit OEIS is

> A049210       a(n) = -product_{k=0..n} (8*k-1); octo-factorial numbers.

In the unix bash shell the symbol "!" means "repeat the previous command". Perhaps in this context "(!^8)" means something like "replace $n$ with $n-8$ in the formula for $a(n)$, so defining a recursion. You could check to see if that reproduces the product in the definition.

Comment: You have to scroll down to the Formula section.